# Firebase (4.0.0): Use of unresolved identifier FirebaseApp when installing FirebaseDatabase

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

This is what happens:

- running on Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)
- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- import Firebase in the Class

[unresolved on Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHW6c.png)

Then I added the Database framework

- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- pod 'Firebase/Database'

[unresolved on FirebaseApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUsTn.png)

It seems that the 2 frameworks are in mutex mode. They cannot coexist.

I have tried everything: update, install, uninstall, recreate the project, recreate the workspace. All.

May you help me. Is there a bug on last Firebase release?

Comment: Could you please post your full Podfile? I suspect I have the answer.

Answer (score 78):

I had a similar issue.

Your import statement would be:

```
import Firebase
```

Make sure restart Xcode and to clean the build folder.

It's working for me & got rid of "Use of unresolved identifier FirebaseApp..." error

**Update:** For Swift 4.2: `FirebaseApp.configure()` does work. *[FIRApp is renamed to FirebaseApp]*

Comment: This is correct if you're on an older version of Firebase (which is what the cocoapods default repo points to). The documentation is written for Firebase 4.8+. Chris Edgington's answer below will fix that by updating your repo (running `pod repo update && pod update`).

Answer (score 50):

```
import FirebaseCore
```

Then you could use `FirebaseApp.configure()`. I'm using swift 4.

Comment: This solved my problem, but also showed me what was wrong in my case. The instructions to install Crashlytics only tell you to add `pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'` to your Podfile, but I think it might be assumed you also have `pod 'Firebase'` in there already too. Adding `Firebase` to my Podfile, allowed me to `import Firebase` instead of `import FirebaseCore`.

Comment: Weird. Docs say to just `import Firebase` which works in `AppDelegate.swift`. But not in another swift file. There I need `import FirebaseCore`

Answer (score 27):

Sounds like you might be using an older version of Firebase. Try -

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

Double check Firebase 4.0 is being installed.

Also try importing the specific modules. So instead of 
`import Firebase` use `import FirebaseDatabase`or `import FirebaseAuth`.

Comment: I've been informed by Firebase guys it is a bug and they are providing a solution. The problem does not happen with Xcode 8.

Comment: My project is written in Swift 2

Comment: @GiancarloMarasso Firebase 4.0.0 was build with Swift 3 in mind since Apple has stopped supporting Swift 2. A workaround you can use in the meantime until you upgrade to Swift 3 is go into the `FIRCoreSwiftNameSupport.h` and `FIRDatabaseSwiftNameSupport.h` and change the line `#define FIR_SWIFT_NAME(X) NS_SWIFT_NAME(X)` to `#define FIR_SWIFT_NAME(X)` (deleting the `NS_SWIFT_NAME(X)`). This will leave the old Firebase naming scheme intact. Unfortunately, you'd have to do this every time you do a `pod update` since it'll be overwritten.

Comment: `pod repo update` and `pod update` worked for me in Xcode 9.0 beta 2 (9M137d). Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

use    FIRApp.configure() instead of Firebase.configure()

Comment: Also make sure you import Firebase.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod update
```

Comment: @nzackoya , in which directory i should update the cocoapods??

Comment: @ArgaPK Your project directory.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `pod 'Firebase/Core'` with `pod 'Firebase'`.
Then run `pod repo update`.

Answer (score 5):

That work today for me:

**1. in Xcode 9.1**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseCrash
import FirebaseAnalytics


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }
```

**2. My PodFile**

```
pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**3. finale:**

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

**4. restart xcode:**

**5. press: shift-alt-command-k (in xcode)**

This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder.It's different from delete derive data.

**6. an clean**

done

Answer (score 4):

In my case it I needed to `import FirebaseCore` instead of `import Firebase` or `import FirebaseRemoteConfig`.

Answer (score 2):

I put in 'Firebase' along w/ 'Firebase/Core' in the podfile and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

and then run this **at the location of the pod file**:

```
pod install
```

After rebuilding my app the error should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Use FIRApp.configure() instead of FirebaseApp.

Answer (score 1):

For those facing the issue with RemoteConfig configuration, adding an extra import:

```
import FirebaseRemoteConfig
```

helped in my case

Comment: In my case it is FirebaseCore that need to import

Answer (score 1):

`import FirebaseCore`

Adding this to the top of the class resolved the issue for me.

FirebaseCore version: 6.29.0

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late but if you are sure your podfile is correct and your app has been building before.
When this error just comes out of the blue, remember that the other thing can go wrong is your Xcode's incremental build folder.

Try this:

1. Quite Xcode
2. Locate your Build folder and DerivedData folder in finder
3. Delete Build folder and DerivedData folder
4. Rebuild via Xcode

Hopefully you'd be fine then.